# Cytoscape.js making a sub-instance from a graph

Tags: cytoscape.js

#### Background

So I have my main graph:

```
var cy = cytoscape { ... }
```

I am running it headless as it is sufficiently large.

I would like to, given a node id (n-id), make a non-headless instance from my main graph, which is based upon all nodes / edges in the neighborhood of degree d centered at n-id.

so the first part isn't too complicated...

```
cy.getElementById('n-id')
```

in principal I should be able to chain methods to get the desired result

```
cy.getElementById('n-id').neighborhood(SELECTOR).add(cy.getElementById('n-id'))
```

where we have the add command because the neighborhood doesn't include the calling node.

#### Questions

So my questions are the following

1.) what is the appropriate selector? `[degree <= d]` doesn't work

2.) now that I have my neighborhood, how do I turn it into a non-headless instance for visualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. `cy2.add( cy1.getElementById('#some-node').closedNeighborhood('[[degree = 5]]') )`

Comment: The filter degree doesn't work because it is the degree of classical graph theory, not degree in the sense of distance.

Comment: Then you'll have to do a bfs and store the distance in each node's data so you can do a `[distance = 5]` filter